# Не работает ajax кнопка "Показать ещё"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку "Показать ещё", но выдаёт ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вид

```
<?php
$per_page = 5;
$ddata = (int)$users_klient_db1;
$entry = 'klient_1';
$count_1 = (int)($ddata/$per_page) + 1;

if($ddata > $per_page) {
?>            
<div class="showMore text-center" data-entry="<?php echo($entry); ?>" data-page="1" data-count="<?php echo($count_1); ?>" data-per="<?php echo($per_page); ?>">
<span class="funner_table_category_skin btn">Показать ещё</span>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
    <script>
            var loadingFlag = false;
          window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){  
            $('.showMore').click(function()
            {
                var but = $(this);
                var contra = $(this).prev();
                var entry = $(this).attr('data-entry');
                var page = parseInt($(this).attr('data-page'));
                var count = parseInt($(this).attr('data-count'));
                var per_page = parseInt($(this).attr('data-per'));
                if (!loadingFlag)
                {
                    console.log('oli');
                    loadingFlag = true;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'get',
                        url: 'http://adsblogger.media/ja',
                        data: {
                            'entry': entry,
                            'page': page + 1,
//                            'page': page,
                            'per_page': per_page,
                        },
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            page++;
                             but.attr('data-page', page);                           
                            loadingFlag = false;                            
                            contra.append(data);
                            if (page >= count) {
                                but.hide();
                            }    
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
            });
    </script>
```

Контроллер

```
$projects_db = ProjectForm::find()->all();
        $platforms_db = PlatformForm::find()->all();

        // Все клиенты
        $users_klient_db = User::find()
            ->where(['role' => ['klient']])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->limit(5)
            ->all();
        $users_klient_db1 = User::find()
            ->where(['role' => ['klient']])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->count();


return $this->render('projects_manager', [
            'platforms_db'           => $platforms_db,
            'users_klient_db'        => $users_klient_db,
            'users_klient_db1'        => $users_klient_db1,
            'klient_no_project_db'   => $klient_no_project_db,
            'klients_in_work_db'     => $klients_in_work_db
        ]);
```

Контроллер от куда тянем данные при нажатии "Показать ещё"

```
public function actionJa()
    {
        //echo "<script>console.log('ja site');</script>";

        //echo Yii::$app->request->get('entry');

            $data = array();
            $entry = Yii::$app->request->get('entry');
            $page = Yii::$app->request->get('page');
            $per_page = Yii::$app->request->get('per_page');
            $off = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
            
            if($entry == 'klient_1') {
                $users = User::find()
            ->where(['role' => ['klient']])
            ->orderBy('id desc')
            ->limit($per_page)
            ->offset($off)
            ->all();    
            }
            
            $data = array(
                'its' => $users,            
            );  
            return  $this->renderPartial($entry, array(
                'data'=>$data,
            ));            
    }
```

Comment: 500 - всегда ошибка на сервере. Включай отладку и используй её (ссылки выше). А также в network в ответе можно смотреть что сервер пишет....

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо
Проблема была в том что вид не мог найти